# Find non-alphanumeric characters with alphanumeric character anywhere before

Tags: python, regex

So I was writing some code, that would take a String, like "This$#is% Matrix#  %!" and delete all non-alphanumeric symbols, that have alphanumeric symbols somewhere on both surrounding them. I managed to get that, but the problem comes with Strings, that have non-alphanumeric symbols before any other symbols. I wanted to do it with a "non fixed lenght" lookback, but that is not possible. Are there any workarounds?
Code and some examples:

```
decodedString = re.sub(r"[^0-9,a-z,A-Z](?=.+[0-9,a-z,A-Z])", " ",decodedString)
print("1st regex: " + decodedString)
decodedString = re.sub(r" (?= .+[0-9,a-z,A-Z])", "", decodedString)
print("2nd regex: " + decodedString)
```

(The second regex deletes spaces, that are twice in a row, but it should also only delete if an alphanumeric character is before it).

"#  @i##U" should become "#  @i U", this one is the only one not working, because it deletes the non-alphanumeric characters at the start (it gives back  "i #U")

"This%%is$Matrix%%$script" should become "This is Matrix script"

"This$#is% Matrix#  %!" should become "This is Matrix#  %!"

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(?<=[^\W_])[\W_]+(?=[^\W_])', ' ', text)
```

*Details*:

- `(?<=[^\W_])` - a letter or digit should be immediately on the left
- `[\W_]+` - one or more non-alphanumeric
- `(?=[^\W_])` - a letter or digit should be immediately on the right.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XWBWbZ/2).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZBQuLD):

```py
import re
texts = ['This%%is$Matrix%%$script', 'This$#is% Matrix# %!']
for text in texts:
    print(re.sub(r'(?<=[^\W_])[\W_]+(?=[^\W_])', ' ', text))
```

Output:

```py
This is Matrix script
This is Matrix# %!
```

Comment: Oh wow this actually worked! And thank you very much for the explanation!